# Notify/Wait Issue When Using Two Threads To Sequentially Call Two Different Functions

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm having an issue synchronizing functions on the same object. In my main class, I have a button that when pressed, should fire two functions sequentially from a different class. The first thread runs fine. I'm thinking the second is getting caught in a deadlock, but idk how. However, when I specify a timeout for the second thread, it fires. Can somebody help me understand what's going on with the notify/wait?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        t = new Thread () 
        {
            public void run ()
            {
                synchronized(this)
                {
                    one();
                    notify();
                }
            }
        };
        thr = new Thread () 
        {
             public void run ()
             {
                 synchronized (this)
                 {
                    try
                    {
                        wait();
                        two();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                 }
             }
         };
        thr.start();
        t.start();
    }
```

Comment: Your title is too general. Please correct it. For hints visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Is this better? @Pshemo

Comment: Not quite. Try to shortly describe your problem instead of telling us that you have one. Let your title be *searchable* for people with same problem.

Comment: What about now? Sorry for the confusion @Pshemo

Comment: Note:  This program has _two_ bugs.  Pshemo's answer talks about one of them, and JJF's answer explains the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm having an issue synchronizing functions on the same object

Problem is that you are not synchronizing on same object/lock because `this` in each of `synchronized(this)` is referring to different instances of `Thread`:

- one from `t`
- one from `thr`

To avoid such problem create explicit lock Object which you will pass to your threads.

Comment: Thank you!! I was thinking I was referring to the class itself!

Comment: Hey @Pshemo, I changed the code up a bit. What do you think?

Comment: @trevalexandro You made two mistakes. First is that you changed location of synchronization from code in threads you are creating, to thread which handles code of `actionPerformed` which means that now these new threads doesn't have *any* synchronization inside them and now you are risking that main thread of Swing applications (EDT) will need to wait for `this` monitor if it is being used elsewhere. Second problem is that you changed your question in a way which makes posted answers no longer valid. That is not how Stack Overflow works. If you have additional question post it as separate one.

Comment: Sorry, I changed it back. @Pshemo

Comment: Hey @Pshemo just wanted to let you know your advice worked, I just created an explicit lock and used its notify/wait methods, worked perf!

Answer (score 1):

It's a race condition whether t or thr enters the synchronized section first.  t could notify before thr waits.

Comment: That makes sense. I thought by starting thr first, it would wait before t even began though. @JJF

Comment: The significance of that being that `o.notify()` does not do _anything at all_ unless some other thread is already waiting in an `o.wait()` call.

Comment: I understand that notify doesn't do anything unless another thread is waiting, but if thr is started first won't it be waiting on t to make that call? @jameslarge

Comment: @trevalexandro, Re, "...if thr is started first won't it be waiting...?"  It's a race.  When your main thread calls `thr.start()` before calling `t.start()`, that might give the `thr` thread a small advantage, but it does not guarantee that the `thr` thread will win the race.

Comment: Oh okay, I understand now. I was thinking thr would sequentially reach wait first. However, both threads will be running concurrently. How do you guarantee that one thread acquires the monitor first then? I know you could put one thread to sleep when started, but I wanted to explicitly handle that @jameslarge

Comment: You could use a `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore` instead of using wait() and notify().  Unlike wait()/notify(), a Semaphore has _state_.  You could initialize the Semaphore to have zero _permits_.  Your `thr` thread could call `semaphore.acquire()` to wait for a permit, and your `t` thread could call `semaphore.release()` when it's OK for the other thread to proceed.

Comment: There's actually lots of classes in `java.util.concurrent` that you could use to solve your problem:  `CountDownLatch`, `CyclicBarrier`, `Phaser`, `Exchanger`, `ArrayBlockingQueue`, `CompletableFuture`,...  Many of them do more than what you need, but all of them can do at _least_ what you need, which is to make one thread wait at a certain point, until another thread says "go".  Semaphore is a good one to learn though because it is versatile, and it is _very_ old, and therefore you will see it in a lot of code and in a lot of text books.

Comment: We went over semaphores in one of my classes, we just didn't have any programming exercises for it. I'm trying to improve my skills at synchronization so I need to go back and do it that way @jameslarge